# Подключение css в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django

Доброго Всем дня! У меня есть проект "proj" на Django, в нем создано приложение "blog". В файле "..../proj/blog/templates/page.tpl" нужно подключить файл "style.css" который лежит в той же папке. Как прописать путь что бы при вызове

```
render_to_response('page.tpl', context)
```

сгенерированая страница находила css файл?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы используете встроенные сервер для разработки, то вам нужно поместить файл стилей в папку со статикой(статическими файлами). Для этого в urls.py вам нужно вставить

```
(r'^statika/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),
```

Вместо слова statika можете написать что угодно, а вместо /path/to/media, полный путь до папки где вы хотите хранить статику( например c:/django_proj/media/ для windows). 
Если вы хотите что бы css файлы лежали вместе с шаблонами то вам нужно указать путь до папки с шаблонами. И тогда в page.tpl вам нужно прописать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/statika/style.css">
```

Вместо statika может быть то слово, которое вы указали в urls.

[Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#how-to-do-it) можно прочитать больше про раздачу статики на сервере разработчика.

Answer (score 5):

В Джанго 1.3 все стало гораздо проще. В шаблоне, например, подключаем css-ку или js:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Ваш settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/personal_site/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', # <--- Добавлено
    ...
    )
```

И еще пара настроек. Почитать подробно можно тут - [the staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).